# For-loop for days over years, python script for targeting data

Tags: python, loops, date, for-loop, calendar

If I want to add a loop to constrain days as well, what is the easiest way to do it, considering different length of month, leap years etc.
This is the script with years and months:

```
yearStart = 2010
yearEnd = 2017
monthStart = 1
monthEnd = 12
for year in list(range(yearStart, yearEnd + 1)):
    for month in list(range(monthStart, monthEnd + 1)):
        startDate = '%04d%02d%02d' % (year, month, 1)
        numberOfDays = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
        lastDate = '%04d%02d%02d' % (year, month, numberOfDays)
```

Comment: ... `for day in range(numberOfDays):`?

Answer (score 4):

If you want only the days then this code, using the [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/) library, is probably the easiest.

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> first_date = pendulum.Pendulum(2010, 1, 1)
>>> end_date = pendulum.Pendulum(2018, 1, 1)
>>> for day in pendulum.period(first_date, end_date).range('days'):
...     print (day)
...     break
... 
2010-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

pendulum has many other nice features. For one thing, it's a drop-in replacement for `datetime`. Therefore, many of the properties and methods that you are familiar with using for that class will also be available to you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use datetime in addition to calendar library. I am exactly not sure on requirements. But it appears you want the first date and last date of a given month and year. And, then loop through those dates. The following function will give you the first day and last day of each month. Then, you can loop between those two dates in whichever way you want.

```
import datetime
import calendar

def get_first_last_day(month, year):
    date = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=1)
    first_day = date.replace(day = 1)
    last_day = date.replace(day = calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1])
    return first_day, last_day
```

Adding the logic for looping through 2 dates as well.

```
d = first_day
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    while d <= last_day:
        print d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        d += delta
```